# Woman wearing modest swim clothing

Tags: women, clothing, tznius-modesty, swimming

Does a woman going swimming with other women need wear modest swimming clothing or can she wear what she desires?

Comment: Why are you wondering about swimming in particular? What about just two girls who are roommates and want to wear comfortable pajamas to sleep?

Comment: @DoubleAA: Because when swimming in particular, one is usually wearing less articles of clothing.

Comment: And therefore what? Do you think that has any halachic import? How is it different from a bedroom or any other circumstance where people aren't fully dressed?

Comment: Isn't there a rule that tzni'ut applies at all times even in one's bedroom by oneself?

Comment: @DanF You may be thinking of ShA OC 2:2 which applies equally to men and women.

Comment: DoubleAA, @DanF is referring to something different. There is extensive halacha as well as machshava about tznius in private, tznius in the home, tznius around holy objects, tznius for its own sake, etc. The rules vary by context within this list and by community.